# Problem with formatting dates for outlook.items.restrict dynamically (under consideration of user configured language)

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I'm using `win32com.client` to automatically generate reports based on my calendar appointments.

To retrieve only the appointments of the current month I use this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict like so:

```
    # a bunch of other code ...
    end = date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y 11:00 PM")
    start = date.today().replace(day=1).strftime("%m/%d/%Y 01:00 AM")
    return calendar_entries.Restrict("[Start] >= '" + start + "' AND [END] <= '" + end + "'")
```

initially, I used `"%d/%m/%Y"` format strings instead of `"%m/%d/%Y"`. However, after recently changing the language on my Windows system from German to English for reasons unrelated to the program at hand, my time restriction code stopped working, leading me on a bug-hunt that ultimately made me discover that the format expected by Outlook depends on the current language. I obviously want my program to work regardless of the language configured by the user, so I'm wondering how to best approach dynamically generating those format strings. Ideally, there would be some builtin method I could use to retrieve the format currently expected by Outlook, maybe someone knows if a method like that exists? Otherwise, I'm generally open to suggestions ..